# call db2 list db directory from c# application

Tags: c#-4.0, db2

I would like to get all the database name inside 1 db2 instances through c# application?

Besides calling 'list db directory', is there any other alternative?

How can i invoke db2cmd from my c# application which the is not same server with the db2 server.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This question sure looks like a duplicate of http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41881/get-all-the-database-in-db2-through-web/41922#comment73783_41922

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to execute that? in the server or in the client?

If it is in the server, you can get all instances by calling db2ilist or with db2greg -dump

- db2greg - http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.trb.doc/doc/r0020699.html
- db2ilist - http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002059.html

However, if you want to know the configured instances in a given node, you need to use db2 list node directory.

A node in a client is a set of cataloged instances with cataloged databases. A node in a DB2 server is an instance with local databases and cataloged instances with cataloged databases.

**For a client machine**

One alternative is to install a DB2 client in your machine, and then you could call db2cmd (db2 list node directory). You have to install the Data Server Client Runtime in order to access the CLP and catalog remote instances/databases.

If you want to develop a only C application, you will use the DB2 API, by calling the sqlenops -
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.api.doc/doc/r0001515.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. The Application server and db server will not be in the same server. Since it is browser based application, the application can be access using any pc. Do you have any example on how to use DB2 API for sqlenops with c# application? I couldn't understand how to invoke the db2 API from c# application. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I do not hava examples of that

Comment: Then do you know roughly how to invoke db2 API from either c# or other application?  Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: The db2 APIs for programs written in C.  So (I think) you'd have to write a DLL in C that can call these other APIs and then use that DLL for your app.